# Create a new project with loopback.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, loopbackjs

I'm trying to use for the first time LoopBack.io and I always get this error when I'm trying to create a new project with this command line:

```
 slc loopback
```

Here is the error:

```
 [Error: `app.boot` was removed, use the new module loopback-boot instead]
```

Can anyone guide me to fix this problem, please? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by re-installing strongloop with an NPM option to avoid permissions troubles:

```
 sudo npm install -g strongloop --unsafe-perm=true.
```